# "Red Heart ❤️" unicode character in ncurses

Tags: c++, unicode, ncurses

Currently using WSL2, C++20, with the preprocessor directives `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1`, `#include <panel.h>`, and flags `-lpanelw -lncursesw`.

Using the code provided below when I try to add the "Red Heart ❤️" character in ncurses, it causes weird bugs on the terminal window, especially when I encase it with a box. I've gotten the same problem on my MacBook as well. When I put the unicode character in a string `"❤️"`, it gives me a `const char[7]`, as opposed to many other unicode characters that give a `const char[5]`. Could this have something to do with the cause of the bugs? I would really appreciate it if someone could give me some insight into this problem.

(Ignore the cursor at the bottom right of some of the pictures, that's just a cursor problem with the terminal in VS Code).

1 Red Heart:

[image] [image]

2 Red Hearts:

[image]

2 Purple Hearts:

[image]

Code:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1

#include <panel.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    raw();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);
    refresh();
    
    WINDOW *win {newwin(8, 16, 10, 10)};
    box(win, 0, 0);
    mvwaddwstr(win, 1, 1, L"❤️");
    mvwaddwstr(win, 1, 5, L"❤️");
    wrefresh(win);

    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: Does the same bug happen in the new Windows Terminal? https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

Comment: The bug doesn't seem to occur in Windows Terminal. Is there a way to solve this problem for the other terminals that have the bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "character" "❤️" you are using is not actually a single character. It is composed of two Unicode characters, "❤"(U+2764) and a modifying U+FE0F, "VARIATION SELECTOR-16" which gives the red style of the emoji.

You can verify the encoded form of a string by typing `echo -n ❤️ | hexdump -C` in WSL console, which should output

```
00000000  e2 9d a4 ef b8 8f                                 |......|
00000006
```

Or with Python,

```
In [1]: heart="❤️"

In [2]: len(heart)
Out[2]: 2

In [3]: hex(ord(heart[0]))
Out[3]: '0x2764'

In [4]: hex(ord(heart[1]))
Out[4]: '0xfe0f'
```

More about [Variation Selectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)).

Comment: I get this when I use the command you provided:
```0000000 9de2 efa4 8fb8 000a
0000007```

I guess it's the same, with different endianness?

Comment: Makes sense if it is endianness, but it shouldn't matter as I am just trying to show this symbol has two Unicode characters.

Comment: I tried `echo ❤️ | hexdump` as recommended. The result was in my case as well like reported by @Locklan. To achieve what you described, it should be [`echo ❤️ | hexdump -C`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/039ab8377b4ea9d5) (or even better [echo -n ❤️ | hexdump -C](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e103b5e4cc30acd)). @Locklan: This UTF-8 encoding (which consists of bytes) - i.e. no endianess issue possible.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks for the `-C` recommendation. I was running off a BSD `hexdump` thus the difference. I'll change my answer since OP's running on WSL.

Comment: This is an interesting answer about a detail of Unicode I totally missed in the past. (Maybe, because I don't need red hearts in my daily business so often - while making software for engineers.) ;-) I hope you will earn the accepted-answer-checkmark (as IMHO your answer deserves it). You already got my up-vote.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I didn't know this before either. It's kinda interesting to find that other coloured hearts all seem to have their own codepoints.